# Retrieving td hidden cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hidden, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr> 
<th class="hidden">id</th> 
<th>name</th> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="hidden">87</td> 
<td>Isle of Palms</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

and then this jQuery code to hide the id column:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
$('.hidden').hide();
});
</script>
```

I need to get the id cell hidden value when I click on any row but I cannot find the right selector. Any help will be appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('tr').click(function () {

     var id = $(this).find('td.hidden').html();
});
```

UPDATE

```
$('tr').click(function () {

     var id = $(this).find('td.hidden:first').html();
});
```

If you have many columns and want to select the first one, you can use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). Remember, this will add click event for all your rows in your table. I suppose you're only intrested in the rows within your tbody, which your example doesn't have. So I would do this instead:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>  
    <tr> 
      <th class="hidden">id</th> 
      <th>name</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="hidden">87</td> 
      <td>Isle of Palms</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and then set click events for tbody rows

```
$('tbody tr').click(function () {

     var id = $(this).find('td.hidden:first').html();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well... actually your code works for the example I post. Sorry about my last comment. But it doesn't work for my real problem. I'm using a table with 15 columns, 7 are hidden and I need to get the first hidden column, it is the id. Best regards.

Comment: I did. Thank you for your interest. Both of your solutions work for the code I posted. But I'm getting null in the real code at every row I click on. The code is basically the same... just more columns. Weird. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Could you copy/paste the real table?

Comment: Not needed... it works! The class had another name in the real thing. I thought hidden was some kind of 'reserved word'. Thank you so much!!! I'm pretty new to jQuery and I've been struggling for hours.

Comment: hidden is a reserved word when it comes to input => type="hidden". Anyway, if my answer was correct, please check it as that.

Answer (score 0):

I am going assume you me the `.text()` of the `<td class="hidden">87</td>` or `87`

You can register a click handler on the `<tr/>` and then find your `<td/>`

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var $idCell = $(this).find("td.hidden");
    if($idCell.length == 1)
    {
      var id = $idCell.text();
    }
});
```

**Edit**

A slightly better option might be to use `.filter()` so you only register event handlers that have a child `<td class="hidden"/>`

```
$("tr").filter(function(){
    return $(this).children("td.hidden").length == 1;
}).click(function(){
    alert($(this).find("td.hidden").text());
});
```

Comment: That would work! Or he could actually write thead and tbody which is W3C standard. And then set click event like this => $('tbody tr').click(function() { ... });

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. May I ask you what is the meaning of .length == 1 ? Sorry still learning ;)

Comment: It is just a way to make sure there is only one hidden td in the returned result set. If you are having problems post a more robust example on http://jsfiddle.net to see where your problem is.